# Create a grid on top of Google maps and get coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this piece of code taken from this link http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_click2addMarkerSquareB.html

```
var map = null;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var encodedPolyline = "";

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.815334, 144.961332),
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"),
    myOptions
);

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.815334, 144.961332);
var radius = 10/2;

var square = new google.maps.Rectangle({bounds:(new google.maps.Circle({center: point, radius: radius}).getBounds()),
    strokeColor: "#ff0000",
    strokeWeight: 1,
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    fillOpacity: 0.0
});
square.setMap(map);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: map.getCenter(), map: map});
```

This creates a square around a centre point. What I now need to work out is how to create a lot of other squares around the main square with the right and top edges aligned creating a grid. The grid should only go to the right and up from the original square.

I tried this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(square.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), square.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng());

    var square = new google.maps.Rectangle({bounds:(new google.maps.Circle({center: point, radius: radius}).getBounds()),
        strokeColor: "#ff0000",
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        fillOpacity: 0.0
    });
    square.setMap(map);
}
```

But this creates the new square centre from the NW point of the last. If possible I would like to specify how large the grid should be i.e. 100 x 100

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Grid is the viewing area of a map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368644/how-to-create-a-grid-is-the-viewing-area-of-a-map)